# php Graph change mark to 100

Tags: php, html

i have a graph and it's generating well as shown below but i want *Marks* (Y-axis) to end at 100 instead of 125
[image]
Here is the sample **index.php**

```
<?php 
    require "chart/chart.php";
        $chart = new KoolChart("chart");
        $chart->scriptFolder="chart";
        $chart->Width = 900;
        $chart->Title->Text = "Student Marks";
        $chart->PlotArea->XAxis->Title = "Tests";
        $chart->PlotArea->XAxis->Set(array("Semester 1","Semester 2","Semester 3"));
        $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->Title = "Marks";
        **$chart->PlotArea->YAxis->LabelsAppearance->DataFormatString = " {0}";**
        $series = new LineSeries();
        $series->Name = "Progess Graph";
        $series->ArrayData(array($test1,$test2,$test3));
     $chart->PlotArea->AddSeries($series);
    ?>
```

The line in ** ** above is the one responsible for Y-axis.

Here is **chart/chart.php**
http://pastebin.com/96TvRcah

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://demo.koolphp.net/Examples/KoolChart/ChartTypes/ScatterLine_Chart/index.php) documentation you need the following:

```
$chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MinValue = 0;
$chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MaxValue = 100;
$chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MajorStep = 10;
$chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MinorStep = 2;
```

So complete code would be:

```
<?php 
    require "chart/chart.php";
    $chart = new KoolChart("chart");
    $chart->scriptFolder="chart";
    $chart->Width = 900;
    $chart->Title->Text = "Student Marks";
    $chart->PlotArea->XAxis->Title = "Tests";
    $chart->PlotArea->XAxis->Set(array("Semester 1","Semester 2","Semester 3"));
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->Title = "Marks";
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MinValue = 0;
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MaxValue = 100;
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MajorStep = 10;
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->MinorStep = 2;
    $chart->PlotArea->YAxis->LabelsAppearance->DataFormatString = " {0}";
    $series = new LineSeries();
    $series->Name = "Progess Graph";
    $series->ArrayData(array($test1,$test2,$test3));
    $chart->PlotArea->AddSeries($series);
```

Comment: Ok you also must specify `MinValue`. Don't forget to upvote and accept! :)

Comment: You need to specify `MinorStep` and `MajorStep` in addition to `MinValue` and `MaxValue`. Updated answer.